# release view in viewDidUnload

Tags: cocoa-touch, ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I know that if I retain an IBOutlet by using property then I have to set it to nil in `viewDidUnload` but what about others?

For example, i have three subviews view1, view2 and view3, that load from nib and that is the controller's header file

```
@interface MyViewController : UIViewController {
    IBOutlet UIView *view1;
    UIView *view2;
    //no reference for view3
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIView *view2;  //property view2 is an IBOutlet!!
@end
```

and method `viewDidUnload`

```
- (void)viewDidUnload {
    self.view2 = nil;
    //[view1 release];
    //view1 = nil;
    [super viewDidUnload];
}
```

do I have to release view1 and set it to nil? or UIViewController will set it to nil for me? 
what about view3?

also do I have to release view1 in `dealloc`?

edit:
I think many people does not understand my question

Firstly, view1 is an IBOutlet which declared as an ivar and assign an ivar will not retain it. I know that UIViewController definitely will retain it but do i have to release it or UIViewController will release it for me? If UIViewController will release it then there is no point that i have to release it again.

Secondly, view2 is also an IBOutlet although it is declared as a property not ivar.

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIView *view2;
```

It is a retain property, therefore set it will retain it so I know that I have to set it to nil in order to release it. I have no problem about it.

For view3, there is no reference for it, therefore I am assuming I don't have to do anything about it. I also assuming there is no need to make a reference for `every` object in nib.

Comment: Why is there no reference for `view3`?

Comment: Not an answer, but if you have a problem understanding reference counts, just log them: `NSLog(@"view1 retainCount: %d", [view1 retainCount])`. This will help you to see which of the views to release. Also play around with the "leaks" instrument (build -> profile). Keep in mind this doesn't always catch leaks, for instance when your viewController is never deallocated (because technically, this isn't a problem - but it's better style to be prepared).

Comment: @Deepak do i have to make a reference for every subview in nib?

Comment: @fzwo i have problem about understanding the ownership of the views that loaded from nib, does MyViewController own the view or its super class(UIViewController) own the view?

Comment: @xlc0212 Practically, your ViewController holds it. Your VC *is* a UIViewController - only with an enhanced, stricter definition. That is the concept of subclassing. Let me recommend a [very good book](http://www.amazon.com/iPhone-Programming-Ranch-Guide-Guides/dp/0321706242/) for learning iOS development. This explains most interesting topics in an easily approachable way. Be aware that it is a learning book, so work through from front to back. This will save you a lot of time and grief with later projects.

Comment: @fzwo It is different between the framework code own the object or the application code own the object even though it is a same class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All outlets are retained by default even if they don't have a property declared for them. So you will need to release them. If you go on to declare an `assign`ed property as an outlet, then you don't need to release but you can't rely on it either as you are not an owner.

So you need to release both `view1` and `view2` as they are declared as outlets. `view3` is a variable that doesn't exist and hence needn't be worried about.

Comment: outlet mention for view2 is here `@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIView *view2;`

Answer (score 0):

When a nib is loaded, all its objects are automatically instantiated and retained.
The file's owner of your nib file is then the owner of your UIView.

If you use  UIView *view2 you can't connect them using interface builder.
So that doesn't make really sense to me.

You have to release in dealloc as well.

```
- (void)viewDidUnload {
  self.view1 = nil;
  self.view2 = nil;
  [super viewDidUnload];
}

- (void)dealloc {
  [self.view1 release];
  self.view1 = nil;
  [self.view2 release];
  self.view2 = nil;
}
```

Comment: I can connect view2 by the property and the property will retain view2 for me. for your `dealloc` code, why release then set to nil? i think this will lead to crash because set the property to nil will release again since this is a retain property